# Zend Framework 1 ini config for ACL

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl

So I have Zend_ACL set-up(based on this: [Zend Framework: need typical example of ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209671/zend-framework-need-typical-example-of-acl) ).

And I have a config file for setting permissions, but my problem is how do I give access to multiple roles to a specific controller.action

```
; roles
acl.roles.guest = null
acl.roles.admin = null
acl.roles.company = null
acl.roles.user = null
acl.roles.super_admin = null

; resources
acl.resources.deny.all.all = guest

acl.resources.allow.index.all = guest
acl.resources.allow.index.all = company
```

So the problem is this one:

```
acl.resources.allow.index.all = guest
acl.resources.allow.index.all = company
```

So my question is how do I set this up in order for multiple roles to have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can tweak the code to make it work for you. Change the ini like

```
acl.resources.allow.index.all = guest,company
```

Then change the code from [Zend Framework: need typical example of ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209671/zend-framework-need-typical-example-of-acl)

```
protected function _addResources($resources) {          

    foreach ($resources as $permissions => $controllers) {         

        foreach ($controllers as $controller => $actions) {
            if ($controller == 'all') {
                $controller = null;
            } else {
                if (!$this->has($controller)) {
                    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource($controller));
                }
            }

            foreach ($actions as $action => $role) {
                if ($action == 'all') {
                    $action = null;
                }
                if ($permissions == 'allow') {
                    if(strpos($role, ',') !== false) {
                        $multipleRoles = explode(',',$role);
                        $this->allow($multipleRoles, $controller, $action);
                    } else {
                        $this->allow($role, $controller, $action);
                    }
                }
                if ($permissions == 'deny') {
                    if(strpos($role, ',') !== false) {
                        $multipleRoles = explode(',',$role);
                        $this->deny($multipleRoles, $controller, $action);  
                    } else {
                        $this->deny($role, $controller, $action);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but my understanding is that it should work.

Comment: It works, you forgot to add $ to $this->deny(multipleRoles, $controller, $action);