# Where can I find the best way of implementing Zend_Auth?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-auth

I've already created the login forms and I can authenticate against a table,

Do I even need to use Zend_Auth?

Where can I find the best way of implementing Zend_Auth?

Thanks

Comment: You mean implementing Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface right?\

Comment: If your experience is anything like mine you should find at least 123 entirely different best ways of doing it.

Comment: my answer is good ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046608/practical-zend-acl-zend-auth-implementation-and-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following method to authenticate:

```
function authenticate ($data)
{
    $db = \Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $authAdapter = new \Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db);

    $authAdapter->setTableName('usuarios2');
    $authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('user');
    $authAdapter->setCredentialColumn('password');
    $authAdapter->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?) and active = 1');


    $authAdapter->setIdentity($data['user']);
    $authAdapter->setCredential($data['password']);

    $auth = \Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

    if ($result->isValid()) {

        if ($data['public'] == "1") {
            \Zend_Session::rememberMe(1209600);
        } else {
            \Zend_Session::forgetMe();
        }

        return TRUE;

    } else {

        return FALSE;

    }
}
```

$data is the post request from the login form, from the controller I call the function like this: 
authenticate($this->_request->getPost())

In any action if you want to verify the identity of the user you just:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $identity = $auth->getIdentity(); //this is the user in my case
}
```

At the login form I have a checkbox (named public) if its checked the the authentication information will be saved in a cookie otherwhise it will be deleted when the user closes the browser (Zend_Session::forgetMe())

This is a quick review of the auth process.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a tutorial from zendcasts. They even provide some unitesting stuff.

http://www.zendcasts.com/zend-acl-with-authentication-and-reflection/2009/06/

I think it's a really good start.