# ACL Ressource (Controller)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

i just implemented ACL in my Zend Framework which already uses Zend Auth.

I want to give access to some controllers and tried it this way:

```
$roleGuest = new Zend_Acl_Role('guest');
$this->addRole($roleGuest);

$this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('supplier'));
$this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));

$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('Articles'));
$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('Index'));

$this->deny();

$this->allow('supplier', 'Articles');

$this->allow('admin', null);
```

But a user, who is supplier (he is really :)) is not able to see the Controller Articles.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

BR frgtv10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046608/practical-zend-acl-zend-auth-implementation-and-best-practices/2047320#2047320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to create a plugin and write something like this

```
    class Application_Controller_Plugin_AclManager extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
   public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $Request)
   {
      $AclManager = new Zend_Acl();

      $AclManager->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('Guest'));
      $AclManager->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('Supplier'), 'Guest');

      $AclManager->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('controller1'));
      $AclManager->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('controller2'));
      $AclManager->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('controller3'));

      $AclManager->allow('Guest', 'controller1', 'index');
      $AclManager->allow('Supplier', 'controller2');
      $AclManager->allow('Supplier', 'controller3');
```

It will work great. In addition you can write

```
if (! $AclManager->isAllowed(USER_ROLE, $Request->getControllerName(), $Request->getActionName()))
      {
         $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(SOME_URL_TO_REDIRECT);
      }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! my problem was the addResource part and to check the current controllername!

Answer (score 0):

The approach from user707795 is good. I build up my resources with Pike_Reflection_Resource to automaticly define your resources. It's not perfectly documented yet but usage is very simple:

You download the latest version of the Pike library
http://code.google.com/p/php-pike/

Then you create a ACL class which extends Zend_Acl:

```
<?php
class Application_Acl extends Zend_Acl
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_addRoles();
        $this->_addResources();
        $this->_setAuthorization();
    }

    /**
     * Adds roles to ACL
     */
    protected function _addRoles()
    {
        /**
         * Get your roles from the application config here or the database like below (Doctrine2)
         */
//        $repository = $this->_em->getRepository('BestBuy\Entity\Usergroup');       

        $roles = array('guest', 'admin', 'moderator');

        foreach($roles as $role) {
            $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role(strtolower($role)));            
        }               
    }

    /**
     * Adds resources to ACL
     * 
     * Here are resources added to the ACL. You don't have to do this manually 
     * because Pike_Reflection_Resource will search automaticly in your controller
     * directories to define which actions there are and adds every resource as:
     * modulename_controller_actionname all lowercase.
     */
    public function _addResources()
    {
        $resourceReflection = new Pike_Reflection_Resource();
        $resources = $resourceReflection->toFlatArray('default');

        foreach ($resources as $resource => $humanValue) {
            $this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource($resource));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets authorization
     */
    public function _setAuthorization()
    {   

        //$permissions = $this->_em->getRepository('BestBuy\Entity\Permission')->findAll();
        /**
         * I retrieve my permissions here from the database but you could receive the
         * from the roles attribute too:
         */
        $resourceReflection = new Pike_Reflection_Resource();
        $resources = $resourceReflection->toArray('default');

        foreach ($resources as $moduleName => $controllers) {
            foreach($controllers as $controllerName=>$actions) {
                foreach($actions as $actionName=>$action) {

                    $resourceName = sprintf('%s_%s_%s',
                        strtolower($moduleName),
                        strtolower($controllerName),
                        strtolower($actionName)
                    );                    

                    if(isset($action['roles'])) {
                        foreach($action['roles'] as $role) {
                            if ($this->hasRole($role) && $this->has($resourceName)) {
                                $this->allow($role, $resourceName);
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }                     
    }
}
?>
```

Then you set up a frontcontroller plugin something just like above:

```
    <?php
class Application_Controller_Plugin_Authorization extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Request
     *
     * @var Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * ACL
     *
     * @var Buza_Acl
     */
    protected $_acl;

    /**
     * Called before Zend_Controller_Front enters its dispatch loop.
     *
     * @param  Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)        
    {        
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_acl = new Application_Acl();

    Zend_Registry::set('acl', $this->_acl);

    $this->_checkAuthorization();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the current user is authorized
     */
    protected function _checkAuthorization()
    {
    $allowed = false;
    $currentResource = sprintf('%s_%s_%s',
        strtolower($this->_request->getModuleName()),
        strtolower($this->_request->getControllerName()),
        strtolower($this->_request->getActionName())
    );

    if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
        $user = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity());

        $identityRole = strtolower($user->getRole()); //make sure you implement this function on your user class/identity!
    } else {
        $identityRole = 'guest';
    }

    if ($this->_acl->hasRole($identityRole) && $this->_acl->has($currentResource)) {
        if ($this->_acl->isAllowed($identityRole, $currentResource)) {
            $allowed = true;
        }           
    }        

    if ($allowed !== true) {                        
        throw new Zend_Controller_Exception('No permission', 403);            
    }        
    }

}
    ?>
```

Finally in your controller/actions you define your permissions as follows:

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    /**
     * @human Some description for the permissions of this action
     * @roles guest|admin|moderator
     */
    public function indexAction() {
    }

    /**
     * @human Only for admins!
     * @roles admin
     */
    public function secretAction() {
    }
}
?>
```

This approach is the best and set-up for small applications. For applications where you want to define the allowed actions in the interface of the application you should leave the roles tag and get the permissions for the database.

Please be aware that code below is not tested but with some reviewing it will work and you can control your permissions in the code.